# jQuery/Timeago - Not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeago

I'm having a problem with Timeago and was wondering if anyone else was having the same problem, and if anyone knows how to fix it.

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("time.timeago").timeago();
});
```

HTML:

```
<time class="timeago" datetime="2013-04-14 16:46:24z">Not working..</time>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cRzLN/

(Try the JSFiddle on different browsers.)

Basically, all I'm trying to do is use timeago. However, it's not working in firefox. It works fine in Chrome, but I would like to know why it isn't working in firefox.

I wasn't using the newest versions of timeago or jQuery, so I updated them both and that didn't help.

Tried switching the location of the Javascript, doesn't seem to help.

Any help is much appreciated. :D

Many Thanks,
Rai McKenzie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked at their examples and compared with your markup. I found **Z** is capital

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
```

Change your code to

```
 <time class="timeago" datetime="2013-04-14 16:46:24Z">Not working..</time>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/cRzLN/1/)